# What is maskgen tool in JavaCard

Tags: javacard

In JavaCard, can somebody please tell me what is the purpose of the maskgen tool? 
What I have heard from my senior colleagues that it is the tool which converts the Java codes into C code for that particular JavaCard platform. But is answer seems to broad and lacking the exact particularity. If the above mentioned purpose is correct then my few questions are

*1. How does it convert the java source code into C code ?*

*2. How can I see the source code of this maskgen tool ?*

*3. How can I convert my Java card source code using maskgen tool?*

Answer (score 2):

Quoted from Java Card 3 Platform Development Kit User Guide:

- **What id Maskgen tool?**

> The maskgen tool produces a mask file from a set of Java Card Assembly
>   files produced by the Converter. The format of the output mask file is
>   targeted to a specific platform. The plug-ins that produce each
>   different maskgen output format are called generators. The supported
>   generators are cref, which supports the Java Card RE, and size, which
>   reports size statistics for the mask. Other generators that are not
>   supported in this release include jref, which supports the Java
>   programming language Java Card RE, and a51, which supports the Keil
>   A51 assembly language interpreter. Java Card Assembly Syntax Example
>   provides additional information about the contents of a Java Card
>   Assembly file.

- **Where I can find Maskgen tool source?**

> The maskgen tool is not available or of use outside of a source
>   release bundle, so [...] if you do not have a source release of the
>   development kit you would have maskgen tool. If you have a source
>   release, you can localize locale-specific data associated with the
>   maskgen tool, see [Localizing With The Development Kit.](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/localizing_with_the_development_kit.htm)

- **How to convert Java Card sources using Maskgen tool?**

Check [Running Maskgen](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/running_maskgen.htm#GUID-7741903C-E995-4C8A-B394-92C05A381352) oracle page:

> **maskgen Example**
>
> This example uses a text file (args.txt) to pass command line
>   arguments to maskgen:
>
> `maskgen -o mask.c cref @args.txt`
>
> where the contents of the file args.txt is:
>
> *first.jca second.jca third.jca*
>
> This is equivalent to the command line:
>
> `maskgen -o mask.c cref first.jca second.jca third.jca`
>
> This command produces an output file mask.c that is compiled with a C
>   compiler to produce mask.o, which is linked with the Java Card RE
>   interpreter. Refer to [Using the Reference Implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/using_the_reference_implementation.htm) for more
>   information about this target platform.

*Above ".JCA" (Java Card Assembly) files are generated using Converter tool. [Here is its manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/guide/running_the_converter.htm).*

**Some related quoted info from [here](http://database.developer-works.com/article/15754767/maskgen):**

> maskgen actually generates a `mask.c` file which contains VM bytecodes
>   that are interpreted by the JCVM and the applet is executed. The
>   `mask.c` file should be loaded onto the card. This method is used only
>   for static use of JavaCard.

And

> Maskgen takes the CAP file (which is generated by the converter ), and
>   generates a `mask.c` file which will be a part of the cref in static
>   cards. The parameters for memory configuration of your MCU/processor
>   can be set in maskgen.cfg file.

Anyway, you need a **binary** release of JCDK to have this tool and its source.

Comment: Is it the responsibility of Maskgen tool to generate the package token numbers and method offsets??